# meteor: value from input fields is not stored to collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

This is a new programming paradigm for me, so if you guys can point out what i'm doing wrong, that would be helpful.

Scenario: The user writes into two input fields and hits enter. The system inserts data into Mongo Db collection.

collection is as follows

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a289685331cc2c9a97c2e6"), "text" : "Hello jack.", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-12T15:36:08.558Z"), "info"
```

: "lee@not.com" }

html

```
<!-- add a form below the h1 -->
<form class="new-task">
<input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Type on, little one" />
<input type="text" name = "info" placeholder="info"/>
</form>
</header>

<br/>

<h1>This is what you wrote</h1>

{{#each tasks}}
{{>task}}
{{/each}}



</body>

<template name="task">
<li>{{text}}, {{info}}</li>
</template>
```

The Js file that does the insert

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });
  // submit form

Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task":function(event){

        var text = event.target.data.value;
        var info = event.target.info.value;


        Tasks.insert({
            text: text,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            info: info
        });


        return  false;
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your question?

I guess: Why is the info field not filled in my collection?

As I see, I would remove the blanks in your template, try:

```
name="info"
```

Cheers
Tom

---

UPDATE: As you can see in the comments dialog, leo.warrior has found the real answer himself and added a submit button.

Comment: Just try before Task.insert once `console.log("Info: %s", info);` and check if the var has correct value. In addition try inside Task.insert once `info: "Sample Text"` as a fixed value.

Comment: I debugged the source, and turns out the form wasn't being submitted on "Enter".
I included in a submit button, and it worked. Thanks Tom, i'm going to accept your answer, because you helped me, when you didn't have to + you lead me down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I made an update on my answer to signal this to other readers.